# $(Document).ready does not fire on code but works in console

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

The script does not work on the code but it works on the console. I have tried putting `$(windows).ready` but still does not work

The script is

```
    <script>
    console.log('1')
    $(document).ready(function() {
     console.log('2')
     $("#nets > #tinsasc").each(function(i){
            console.log('3')
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('4')
                $("#nets > #tinsasc").eq(i).addClass("isshowing");
            }, 200 * (i+1));
        });
        console.log('5')
        });
     </script>
```

Kindly help me I have working on this from past few days and not able to solve it. Kindly please free to ask me if I have not explained it well.

Comment: Please show your HTML code.

Comment: Side note, the scroll event fires *a ton* per scroll.  You are going to want to most likely throttle/debounce this some and at the very least, limit the number of lookups you are performing in the handler and used cached variable references instead.

Comment: Are you using a really old version of Internet Explorer? 8 and below doesn't initialise console unless the console itself is open

Comment: does it throw an error, or just not work?

Answer (score 1):

Id's are unique.  As such `$('#nets')` will only find one element, and the `i` will only ever be zero.  If you are expecting to find multiple elements you should change it to find by another selector that can find multiple, such as a class.

The same applies to `$("#nets > #tinsasc")`.  There can only be one element with the id 'tinsasc' so this lookup could just be `$("#tinsasc")` and will also never return more than one element.

Comment: tried with classes instead of divs but still does not work. It works on the console but the script does not work on the code